# How can i create concave border?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to create a shape like exactly [this](http://jsfiddle.net/KcP5k/) but not on left and right border. i want to act on top and bottom border.  is there a way to do it without border-radius
 i tried to do it by changing the corner in border-radius command like this:

```
   border-radius: 60px 0 0 60px / 300px 0 0  300px;
   display: block;
   content: '';
   position: relative;
```

i do not understand well that what does he do on border-radius. he divide two input!!! can we use *,/,+ and - operator in css i haven't seen like this before and when i searched in google i could not find anything!!
but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. The fiddle you provided is using pseudo elements (:before and :after) to achieve the effect, so I adjusted their height/width and border-radius values:

```
#test{
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    background: green;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

#test:before{
    background: white;
    height: 15px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#test:after{
    background: white;
    height: 15px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0 ;
    display: inline-block;
    content: '';
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KcP5k/24/

Comment: Also, if you ever have trouble with the border-radius values there are some helpful tools online:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Tools/Border-radius_generator

Comment: Not a problem! If this was the right answer, please accept it so I get credit ;)

Answer (score 1):

Easy way will be to rotate it 90 degrees and change the height & width:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* IE */
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

Comment: it is cool but unfortunately i have a picture as background and if i rotate it 90deg it would be crashed. and also this css3 command does not support in ie 8 and 7 and cause a lot of problem

Answer (score 1):

What you need is reposition the `after and before` pseudo-elements like this:

```
#test:before{
   border-radius: 0 0 100px 100px / 0 0 60px 60px;
   display: block;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
}
#test:after{
  border-radius:100px  100px 0 0/ 60px 60px 0 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KcP5k/23/)**

*[Here](http://www.sitepoint.com/setting-css3-border-radius-with-slash-syntax/)* you can know the use of the `/` on the `border-radius` syntax.